# Can't configure gr-ais

Tags: compiling

http://www.reddit.com/r/RTLSDR/comments/1mcikt/for_the_nautical_set_rtlsdr_with_grais_and_opencpn/
following the above, I get this error

```
scott@scott-P5QC:~/gr-ais/build$ cmake ../
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.6") 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:94 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Gnuradio" that is
  compatible with requested version "3.7.6".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gnuradio/GnuradioConfig.cmake, version: 3.7.2.1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/scott/gr-ais/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
scott@scott-P5QC:~/gr-ais/build$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application that you're trying to build requires Gnuradio 3.7.6 but only 3.7.2 is available from Ubuntu repositories on a 14.04 system.

You'll have to build Gnuradio from source:

> Open a terminal window, move to the directory you would like the
>   source files to be stored (e.g. `cd src/`), remove old build-gnuradio
>   file, and run this command:
>
> ```
> $ wget http://www.sbrac.org/files/build-gnuradio && chmod a+x ./build-gnuradio && ./build-gnuradio
> ```

Source: [Installing GNU Radio From Source](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGRFromSource#Using-the-build-gnuradio-script)

Comment: Ok, I checked the green check. You did a very nice job on that script!